# How to create in TeamCity automatically new build config. for new branches in Git?

Tags: git, visual-studio, teamcity, visual-studio-2015

We use TeamCity as our CI machine for building Visual Studio 2015 projects. Currently it builds automatically each push in few selected branches.

I'd like to configure the build server to **automatically create new build configurations for new branches** by copying the config setting from master build configuration so I don't have to create these configurations manually.

Is this possible right now? Thanks

Comment: I've seen this before but I don't know how it was done. If you also run GitHub, then you can connect the two. TC will use the GitHub API to detect such changes and configure itself.

Comment: why do you want to create clones of build configs instead of running the same build config against a different branch?

Comment: I think running the same config against new branches is fine, if it can be configured that way?

Answer (score 1):

TeamCity 7+ has support for Git feature branches which will automatically build all branches matching a pattern, see the [TeamCity documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Working+with+Feature+Branches) for more details and how to set one of these build configurations up.

If you want to keep separate build configurations, then you will need to have something external create build configurations from a template for each branch via the TeamCity API. I posted about [using LibGit2Sharp and the TeamCity API](http://jonorossi.com/blog/2011/11/27/sync-teamcity-build-configurations-with-git-branches/) to do this a few years ago.